# CI Deploy of Azure Functions project in solution containing a web project

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-functions

We have a solution that contains (among other things) an Azure Functions project, a Web application project and a WCF project. The solution is hosted in VSTS as a Git repository.

I have used the "Configure continuous integration" button in the Azure portal > Function app settings to select the repository, but when the build is triggered and deployed, according to the logs generated it's trying to deploy the Web app rather than the Functions.

How can I configure a CI build to deploy the Azure Functions project from that solution?

Comment: What's the result with Fabio's solution? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Not yet. Will update this question when I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to customize your deployment and set the target project as documented [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments).

More specifically, you want to use the `project` configuration to point to your azure functions project/folder (using a deployment file, or config setting)

Comment: Thank you again for your support.  I'll give this a try over the weekend.